# Java Applet - version 7 update 51 - "Trust for: <url>fpApplet/FDxSDKPro.jar has ended: Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 CET 1970"

Tags: java, applet, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

After update to Java version7 update 51, I purchased the code signing certificate and signed my applet(s). I have main applet (AppletDemo.jar) and another two applets (commons-codec-1.7.jar and FDxSDKPro.jar) which are used by main applet. I signed them all, with DigiCert certificate.

All of them are signed, and verified with jarsigner tool where i get such message:

```
*s = signature was verified
m = entry is listed in manifest
k = at least one certificate was found in keystore
i = at least one certificate was found in identity scope
jar verified.*
```

When I try to load the applet I get the following message in the java debug console (the real url is replaced with  tag):

```
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for <url>/fpApplet/AppletDemo.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for <url>/fpApplet/FDxSDKPro.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for <url>/fpApplet/commons-codec-1.7.jar
security: Certificate revocation enabled. Disable security validation optimizations.
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: Trust for: <url>fpApplet/FDxSDKPro.jar has ended: Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 CET 1970
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: Trust for: <url>/fpApplet/commons-codec-1.7.jar has ended: Thu Jan 01 01:00:00    CET 1970
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API 
network: Cache entry not found [url: <url>/fpApplet/, version: null]
security: Grant socket perm for <url>/fpApplet/ : java.security.Permissions@199a51e (("java.net.SocketPermission" "<url>" "connect,accept,resolve"))
basic: Your security settings have blocked an untrusted application from running
basic: exception: Your security settings have blocked an untrusted application from running.
com.sun.deploy.security.BlockedException: Your security settings have blocked an untrusted application from running
```

I assume, that Applet is blocked because of this and two following lines **(Trust for: fpApplet/FDxSDKPro.jar has ended: Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 CET 1970)**.

I do not know how this can happen if jars are signed? Has anyone had such problems?

Answer (score 1):

Bydefault the JAVA security in version 7 is high, so change the security to medium from control panel.follow the link http://www.java.com/en/download/help/jcp_security.xml

Comment: Yes, this is solution for me, but not for the users who will access the applet. They will not change their security level.

Comment: *"The user need to change the setting manually."*  What the user *should do* is ignore any such advice as nonsense and immediately black-list that site and find another app.  Truly, this is very poor advice.  :(

Comment: @AndrewThompson i can't understand.You mean to say that thr is another way to change the security setting ? Please advice

Comment: No, there isn't.  The developer should digitally sign the code using a valid certificate.  And spell out all 5 letters of words like 'there', typing 'thr' makes you sound like a *lazy* teenager.

Comment: @AndrewThompson can you provide me link to understand it. Thnks for explanation

Comment: @Andrew i agree with you. Developer should digitally sign the coude using a valid certificate. As you saw, two of three are showing (Trust for: <url>/fpApplet/commons-codec-1.7.jar has ended: Thu Jan 01 01:00:00    CET 1970) which means something isnt correctly signed. This two packages are not compiled by me, and I do not have source files for it. Can that be a problem?

Comment: You can digitally sign code for which you only have the binary.  OTOH if you cannot get a properly signed version of the original API, you should really be questioning the *wisdom* of using that API **at all.**